# Can't seem to understand c++ shared_ptr and reliable pointers to their representing objects

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, minko

I'm a c++ newcomer and trying to work with the gameengine framework minko. Minko uses shared_ptr very excessively and I have issues understanding how exactly they work, since they seem to escape general c++ *ptr logic.

Somewhere in the initialization phase, several objects are created and obtained via their member functions, such as canvas, sceneManager and the rootNode object.
I'm trying to tie them all together inside a Game class, which, apart from some game logic, should contain a pointer to each of those important engine objects.

I'm running into the problem, that my initial attempts to get this working resulted in duplicated objects, because function calls didn't work, just nothing happened. After some debugging, I added printf functions after the pointer assignments to see where they actually point and they point to different memory adresses, which makes me wonder if they are actually duplicated by the process or some other arcane magic is happening.

Lets start with the objects.

```
std::shared_ptr<minko::Canvas> canvas = Canvas::create("RenderTarget", 1280, 1024);
std::shared_ptr<minko::component::SceneManager> sceneManager = SceneManager::create(canvas->context());
std::shared_ptr<minko::scene::Node> root = scene::Node::create("root")
    ->addComponent(sceneManager);
```

Every one of those objects contains a ::Ptr member attribute, which seems to contain the pointer directly. I didn't find any reference to this in the shared_ptr documents, so I assume this must be specific to the game engine.

Now I have my Game class:

```
class Game
{
    minko::Canvas::Ptr _canvas;
    minko::scene::Node _root;
    minko::component::SceneManager _sceneManager;
}
```

And somewhere in the same function those above objects are created, the assignment:

```
_canvas = canvas;
_root = root;
_sceneManager = sceneManager;
```

I tried a different assortment of *'s and &'s before and after each variable, trying out all sorts of combinations of pointers, direct values, pointer-pointers, but each time I came to my two debug calls:

```
printf("MEMTEST: canvas: %p vs %p , root: %p vs %p , scenemgr: %p vs %p\n", _canvas, canvas, _root, root, _sceneManager, sceneManager);
printf("MEMTEST: canvas: %X vs %X , root: %X vs %X , scenemgr: %X vs %X\n", _canvas, canvas, _root, root, _sceneManager, sceneManager);
```

The memory values were different, leading me to believe they don't point to the same object.

Now, where do I go from here? The documentation didn't really help me, just a huge amount of stuff I don't completely understand yet and it seems that all those websites I found do require a huge amount of c++ knowledge I don't yet have. There must be an easier way to understand this instead of having to amass 5+ years of C++ guruship.

Comment: Long story short: All the smart pointers (`unique_prt` and `shared_ptr`) do is delete the raw pointer they "own" when they fall out of scope using RAII. A `shared_prt` basically keeps a reference count, and deletes the owned pointer when this count drops to 0.

Comment: Please turn on your compiler warnings. You're passing full objects to printf, which does not do anything sensible and therefore all compilers have warnings for it. The answers below answer your actual question, but by turning on compiler warnings you can find many such problems and their solutions yourself. Remember: the compiler is not your enemy; warnings are just things that are 99.9% wrong instead of 100% wrong.

Comment: Thank you dascandy, I figured that out shortly after I submitted the comment that passing whole objects doesn't make sense at all. I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

`_root` and `_sceneManager` are declared to be objects, not pointers. They're never going to refer to the same objects you created with the `create` function.

I'm not familiar with the library, but I guess you want to use their `Ptr` typedefs (which alias the appropriate shared pointer types), just like you're already doing for `_canvas`.

```
class Game
{
    minko::Canvas::Ptr _canvas;
    minko::scene::Node::Ptr _root;
    minko::component::SceneManager::Ptr _sceneManager;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::shared_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) function to access the managed object pointers with the `printf()` statements.

```
printf("MEMTEST: canvas: %p vs %p , root: %p vs %p , scenemgr: %p vs %p\n"
      , _canvas.get(), canvas.get()
      , _root.get(), root.get()
      , _sceneManager.get(), sceneManager.get());
printf("MEMTEST: canvas: %X vs %X , root: %X vs %X , scenemgr: %X vs %X\n"
      , _canvas.get(), canvas.get()
      , _root.get(), root.get()
      , _sceneManager.get(), sceneManager.get());
```

As they are they're pretty useless, to compare anything from the `shared_ptr<>` instances.